# Apply a function to a subset of data and output all subsets of data into one dataframe in R

Tags: r, loops

I have patient messaging data similar to the data below.

The MessageID is each individual message and the ParentMessageID is the MessageID of the immediately preceding thread.

The goal is to have a "threadID" with the same MessageID across a message thread, making the first "MessageID/Parent MessageID" or root message the threadID.

```
df <- data.frame(
  PatientID = c("XXX", "XXX", "XXY", "XXY", "XXZ", "XXZ"), 
  MessageID = c("A", "B", "AA", "BB", "AAA", "BBB"),
  ParentMessageID = c(NA, "A", NA, "AA", NA, "AAA"), 
  ThreadID = c("A", "A", "AA", "AA", "AAA", "AAA")
)
```

To achieve this, I have the below function which works, however, the dataset I have has 20 million messages so to search for the "root" thread of each message takes multiple days to run.

```
getThreadRoot <- function(search_message, df) {
  parent <- subset(df, MessageID==search_message)$ParentMessageID
  if(length(parent) == 0) {return(NA)} # A parent exists but it wasn’t found in the data
  if(is.na(parent)) { return(search_message) }
  getThreadRoot (parent, df)
}

df$ThreadID <- sapply(df$MessageID,  getThreadRoot, df = )
```

I was hoping to make the runtime more efficient by subsetting the dataset by each unique PatientID since the same patient should be messaging across a thread, then apply the function on the smaller subsetted dataset by iteration of PatientID, then append each iteration of PatientID "getThreadRoot" function results into one dataframe.

I have tried the below:

```
#create a counter patient variable in original dataframe
df <- df %>%
  group_by(PatientID) %>%
  mutate(counter_patient = cur_group_id())

#save number of unique patients for loop
maxpatient <- max(df$counter_patient)

for (i in 1:maxpatient){ 
  #subset dataframe for each patient
  patient[i] <- subset(df, counter_patient=i)
  #search for root thread from subsetted data
  patient[i]$ThreadID <- sapply(patient[i]$MessageID, getThreadRoot, df = patient[i])
  #append the previous dataframe to current iteration of dataframe
  patientall <- rbind(patient[i], patient[i-1])
  #remove previous dataframe
  rm(patient[i-1])
  }
```

The above loop doesn't work for the following reasons:

1. It's hard to create dynamic dataframe names based on a loop and doing so would clutter up the workspace with the amount of patients I have in my dataset.
2. I'm new to R but it looks like R would go through the iteration of i in the first statement completely before moving onto the next statement which would defeat the purpose of what I'm trying to do.

Ultimately, I want to apply my "getThreadRoot" function to smaller pieces of my dataset (unique patients) to help with runtime, and append all these smaller pieces into one dataframe in the end.

Comment: The desired output would be to have a new variable called “ThreadID” with the same MessageID across a thread. So for example, for patient “xxx” the threadID would be “A” for the two rows. Did you plug in the data frame name and replace df with the data frame name in the sapply statement? 

the function works but it takes a really long time to run with how large my dataset is so I was hoping to parse the data by patient ID, and run the function for each individual patientID, and append all the results.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm mistaken, but the following works (though perhaps not on the larger dataset, I'm not entirely sure):

```
df |> mutate(ThreadID = first(MessageID), .by = PatientID)
```